# Insert frontmatter property in markdown body in Astro

Tags: markdown, astrojs, yaml-front-matter

I have this frontmatter heading a .md file in Astro.

```
---
title: A great movie
director: John Doe
---
```

I thought that a syntax like `[actor]`, or `{{actor}}`, or `{frontmatter.actor}` or something similar would allow me use the properties as variables INSIDE the markdown body and they will be rendered with the proper values.

```
---
title: A great movie
director: John Doe
---

## My thoughts about {{actor}}

We all know the great director {{director}} and we have seen all his films.
```

Isn't it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing the [Astro MDX integration](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/integrations-guide/mdx/) with:

```
npx astro add mdx
```

you can use the following [syntax in any `.mdx` file](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/markdown-content/#using-frontmatter-variables-in-mdx):

```
---
layout: '../../layouts/BlogPostLayout.astro'
title: A great movie
director: John Doe
---

## My thoughts about {frontmatter.title}

We all know the great director {frontmatter.director} and his films.
```

Comment: Only with .mdx? Not in a regular .md file?

Comment: @NachoB yes really